# Adding a user specific website to a domain

Tags: google, domains, subdomain, users

I just got a domain (first time) and set it up with Google Apps.

I was wondering if it was possible to set up personal websites for individual users on the domain using notation such as `abc@xyz.com` such that typing `abc@xyz.com` would take you to user `abc`'s personal page and `def@xyz.com` would take you to user `def`'s personal page.

I'm a newbie so be gentle :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the way you describe the URL would have to be `yourdomain.com/username` or username.yourdomain.com.

You could achieve this with [Google sites](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/sites.html) which should be included in your Google Apps package. Basically have each user create their own site and amend the DNS to forward the user to the right URL.

Comment: OK... you lost me at amend... total newbie... I'll look that up and see if I can figure it out...

Comment: Just out of curiosity.... I have seen sites that use the @ to specify user... is that only possible with SSL in a username:password@url.com situation

Comment: In fact that's the way of specifying username and password for FTP.

Comment: @paulmorriss OK. Now I'm confused. I just went to an ASPX website for a company I'm doing an Android app for. The website asked me for a username and password... instead of responding in the browser window I cancelled and appended the username:password@ to the website and it works. Are you telling me that website is FTP ?? (Can't give you the link, sorry)

Comment: @SaadFarooq basically there is an FTP client built into some browsers and this is a way of passing the FTP login details in a url string.

Comment: @SaadFarooq no problem - let us know if you need more help

Comment: @SaadFarooq I'd forgotten about that, but you can use the username and password in a URL for what is called HTTP authentication too.

Comment: @paulmorriss Yeah... that sound more like it. I was thinking of somehow faking HTTP Authentication to make users have the same email address and website.... that would be cool... seems unlikely since we'd have to have a password anyway